# R dplyr: mutate a column for specific row range

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to modify the values of a column for rows in a specific range. This is my data:

```
df = data.frame(names = c("george","michael","lena","tony"))
```

and I want to do the following using `dplyr`:

```
df[2:3,] = "elsa"
```

My attempt at it is the following, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
df = cbind(df, rows = as.integer(rownames(df)))
dplyr::mutate(df, ifelse(rows %in% c(2,3), names = "elsa" , names = names))
```

which gives the result:

```
Error: unused arguments (names = "elsa", names = c(1, 3, 2, 4))
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Look at `?data.frame` more carefully than you might have so far, and consider the possibilities offered by the `stringsAsFactor` parameter. You should also explain what you intend .... replacement or "interposition". And PLEASE, do not use `names` as a column name. The R interpreter may be able to keep stratight what is a function and what is an R 'name' but I doubt either of us will.

Comment: I want to use dplyr because I am trying to make my code faster. I am working with a very large data frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is a little vague, but I think OP is trying to just replace certain values in a data frame using indexing. As the comment above noted the example dataframe's column is comprised of a factor variable, which makes replacing the value behave differently than you might expect. There are two ways to get around this.

The first (more verbose) way is to force `df$names` to be a character variable instead of a factor. Then using indexing to select the value you'd like to change and replace it:

```
df$names = as.character(df$names)
df$names[c(2,3)] = "elsa"
```

Alternatively, you can set `stringsAsFactors = TRUE` and proceed as above.

```
df = data.frame(names = c("george","michael","lena","tony"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df$names[c(2:3)] = "elsa"

   names
1 george
2   elsa
3   elsa
4   tony
```

Definitely check out `?data.frame` to get a fuller explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Convert `names` to a character vector explicitly and use `replace`:

```
df %>% mutate(names = replace(as.character(names), 2:3, "elsa"))
```

**Note:** If `names` were already a character vector we could have done just:

```
df %>% mutate(names = replace(names, 2:3, "elsa"))
```

Answer (score 2):

The factor answers are faster, but you can do it with `dplyr` like this (notice that the column *must* be of type `character` and not `factor`):

```
df <- data.frame(names = c("george","michael","lena","tony"), stringsAsFactors=F)
oldnames <- c("michael", "lena")
df <- mutate(df, names=ifelse(names %in% oldnames, "elsa", names))
```

Another way is to do something like

```
oldnames <- c("michael", "lena")
df$names[df$names %in% oldnames] <- "elsa"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this using `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), specify the row index as `i` and assign (`:=`) 'elisa' to the 'names'.  As the OP mentioned about large dataset, using the `:=` from `data.table` will be extremely fast.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[2:3, names := 'elisa']
df
#    names
#1: george
#2:  elisa
#3:  elisa
#4:   tony
```